# append a div with class "modal-trigger" using jquery.append() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

i have a modal named "modalcreatelist" using materializecss. the modal will triggered when some div is clicked using an a href tag.

```html
<div id="modalcreatelist" class="modal"> 
  <div class="modal-content"> 
    <div class="col s12 m6 l12"> 
      <div class="row"> 
        <h6><b>Create a list..</b></h6> 
          <div class="divider"></div> <p>Title</p> 
          <input type="text" placeholder="Title.." id="listTitle"> 
          <input type="hidden" id="hiddenListId" value="<?php foreach($board as $r) {echo $r->boardId;}?>"> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
      <div class="modal-footer"> <a class="waves-effect waves-red btn-flat modal-action modal-close">Close</a> <a class="waves-effect waves-red btn-flat modal-action modal-close" onclick="createList()">Save</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

so i use this html code to trigger the modal, this works perfectly fine

```html
<div id="invoice-line" class="left-align white-text">
   <a href="#modalcreatelist" class="modal-trigger white-text">Add a List..
   </a>
</div>
```

however when i move the code to my javascript file, i try to append the div using jquery .append()
and it is not working
the class "modal-trigger" is not loaded at all
the url is showing like 'localhost/project#modalcreatelist'

```
$("#divCreateList").append'(<div id="invoice-line" class="left-align white-text"><a href="#modalcreatelist" class="modal-trigger white-text">Add a List..</a></div>')
```

Comment: Where is `#somediv`? And, are you adding your script reference at the end of your `body` tag, but after your JQuery script reference?

Comment: Where is 'somediv'? You need to add # in front to select by id.

Comment: im sorry, "somediv" is actually $("#divCreateList")

Comment: @ScottMarcus i put my js files on <head> tag, all of my js files

Comment: Then you must place your JQuery code above in a `document.ready()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebind `modal-trigger` after adding it to DOM. It works the first time cause the bind is done based on class name on `document.ready`. You need to add an event listener for click on `modal-trigger` and add the logic that opens your modal.

That means, after adding the content through JavaScript. You have to write something like. 
`$('.modal-trigger').on('click', function() { open modal; })`

replace 'open modal' with your logic.

Comment: Or, you can just use event delegation and then you don't have to rebind.

Comment: If the default behaviour does not use event delegation, he still needs to rebind (and come up with logic for modal opening) and then maybe make use of event delegation to avoid further need for rebinds.

Comment: It's easy, get the href attribute of the modal-trigger and use that to identify your modal, then look for native JavaScript methods of the library that handles your modals. (how to init, then open).

Comment: If the original event binding is done via event delegation, no further binding is needed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, if the initial behaviour used event delegation, it would have worked.